# Logic of PHP & Get Section of an Array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, logic, output

I've found a piece of code which displays a ping to a server via php, I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve a different output, but I am struggling to determine the logic.

**Code:**

```
             <?php
             $cmd = "ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1";

             $descriptorspec = array(
             0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
             1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
             2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
             );
             flush();
             $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
             echo "<pre>";
             if (is_resource($process)) {
                 while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
                     print $s;
                 }
             }
             echo "</pre>";
             ?>
```

**Current Output:**

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=54 time=28.278 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 28.278/28.278/28.278 ms
```

**Wanted Output:**

I only want the ms value or "time"

```
28.278
```

**Trials:**

I've tried to grab the value of "`$s`" or "`$pipes`" variables/arrays, including some trial of array values "`[1]`" etc. by running it through the following code:

```
str_replace("time=","@@",$test_stringget_ping_res);
str_replace(" ms","@@",$test_stringget_ping_res);
```

But I am getting "Failed to Open Rule File".

Comment: So you only need **time** ?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, from the second line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match()` as following.

```
preg_match('/time=(.*?) ms/', $s, $m );
print $m[1];
```

Your code will be as follows:

```
 if (is_resource($process)) {
 while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
     preg_match('/time=(.*?) ms/', $s, $m );
     print $m[1];
     print $s;
   }
 }
```

**Explanation:** Simply capturing everything between `time=` and `ms`.

**<kbd>[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/8VKCNB)</kbd>**

Check [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) documentation for use.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your command to:

```
ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | tail -1 | cut -d/ -f 5
```

Comment: Thanks, however I require the entire output elsewhere also!